# Set JSON Naming Convention for Refit client

Tags: c#, json, .net, httpclient, refit

I'm trying to use the Refit library (https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) to create an http client for my service, but there was a problem. I want to use `SystemTextJsonContentSerializer` for serialization and set the naming convention of json object properties for the request body. However, I did not find in the documentation how to do this. There is only an example for `NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer` (see https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#json-content). How can this be done for `SystemTextJsonContentSerializer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using `System.Text.Json`, [Refits source code](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/0baec2ea6f462264696fe476a88dfc267b527ad7/Refit/SystemTextJsonContentSerializer.cs#L47) has a public constructor for the `SystemTextJsonContentSerializer` class that takes in a `JsonSerializerOptions` object and sets it for the instance:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new <see cref="SystemTextJsonContentSerializer"/> instance with the specified parameters
/// </summary>
/// <param name="jsonSerializerOptions">The serialization options to use for the current instance</param>
public SystemTextJsonContentSerializer(JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions)
{
      this.jsonSerializerOptions = jsonSerializerOptions;
}
```

Because the [`RefitSettings` class constructor](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/0baec2ea6f462264696fe476a88dfc267b527ad7/Refit/RefitSettings.cs#L33) takes in a `IHttpContentSerializer`, and since the `SystemTextJsonContentSerializer` class (and the `NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer` class for that matter) implements said interface, you should be able to do:

```
var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions 
{
    //set some options such as your preferred naming style...
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true
};

var settings = new RefitSettings(new SystemTextJsonContentSerializer(jsonSerializerOptions), null, null); 
//the two null parameters are for IUrlParameterFormatter? and IFormUrlEncodedParameterFormatter? objects
```